# How to add a option to Select Dropdown and Make it first in list

Tags: jquery, html

I have a Select control on my webpage where the options are creating from the DB and i dont have access to the source code.

I need to add a option to the List so i used jQuery and did this.

```
jQuery("select[id$='ShippingSubdivisionDropDownList']").append('<option value=NULL>Select County/State</option>');
```

This works but it adds the option at the end of the list. How can i add this option to the beginning of the Select List?

EDIT: Ok, it turned out to be a simple replace of append with prepend. But how can i make this new option the default selected option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION I**

Use `.prepend()` instead:

```
jQuery("select[id$='ShippingSubdivisionDropDownList']").prepend('<option selected="selected" value="NULL">Select County/State</option>');
```

and for making it selected, add attribute `selected='selected'`

**SOLUTION II**

You can also use:

```
jQuery("<option>", { value: 'NULL', selected: true }).prependTo("select[id$='ShippingSubdivisionDropDownList']");​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
jQuery("select[id$='ShippingSubdivisionDropDownList']").prepend('<option value=NULL>Select County/State</option>');
```

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7EaQ6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try about this one,
var choices = [];
choices[0] = "one";
choices[1] = "two";

function addInput(divName) {
    var select = $("<select/>")
    $.each(choices, function(a, b) {
        select.append($("<option/>").attr("value", b).text(b));
    });
    $("#" + divName).prepend(select);
}
```